# Install kotlin in ubuntu image getting error

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kotlin

I am getting an error while installing kotlin in ubuntu image.

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y zip
RUN curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
RUN chmod a+x "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
RUN sdk install kotlin
```

Getting error

```
Step 10/35 : RUN sdk install kotlin
---> Running in 9282af532681
/bin/sh: sdk: command not found
ERROR: Service 'myproject' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c sdk install kotlin' returned a non-zero code: 127
```

Answer (score 4):

```
FROM ubuntu:16.04
RUN apt-get update
RUN rm /bin/sh && ln -s /bin/bash /bin/sh
RUN apt-get -qq -y install curl
RUN apt-get install -y unzip
RUN apt-get install -y zip
RUN curl -s https://get.sdkman.io | bash
RUN chmod a+x "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
RUN source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh" && sdk install kotlin
```

Each RUN have their own "session". So `RUN sdk install kotlin` will not know about previous `source` command.

---

Multiple RUN is not optimal: each RUN will create a layer.

---

Looks like you want to create docker image with Kotlin JVM. Then you need standard `openjdk:8-jdk` (Or what version you want) and then just put there your jar file.

Comment: Thanks for reply, i am trying to install all programming languages in one docker image for my project. I want to install kotlin in ubantu image.

Comment: Usually docker used to run one process. (https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/447/why-it-is-recommended-to-run-only-one-process-in-a-container). Consider to use one container for one process/application. Then you could use existing containers with particular languages. I advise you to pay attention to containers based on alpine Linux they are small and fast.